# Акселлерометр, Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Снимаю показания для движения тела в зависимости от наклона устройства
Код взял с офф. мануала по Input

```
public float speed;
Vector3 dir;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
speed = 10.0f;
dir = Vector3.zero;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () { // пробовал и просто с Update, вроде с физикой лучше использовать Fixed


    dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;
    dir.z = Input.acceleration.y;
    // clamp acceleration vector to the unit sphere
    //if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
        //dir.Normalize();

    // Make it move 10 meters per second instead of 10 meters per frame...
    dir *= Time.deltaTime;

    // Move object
    transform.Translate(dir * speed);
}
```

Всё работает, причем отлично и отзывчиво, но иногда, когда тела касаются друг друга(например игрок касается стенок и скользит некоторое время вдоль них) что то сбивается и одна из осей инвертируется, либо вообще начинает двигаться по вертикали! Прыгает игрок, на котором скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую вместо `transform.Translate()` использовать `rigidbody.AddForce()`

Необходимо в `Start` получать компонент `Rigidbody`, при помощи метода `GetComponent<>()` и использовать данный компонент для движения игрока.

Демонстративный код:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class AccelerationTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    private new Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;


    private void Start () 
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>()
    }

    private void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;
        dir.z = Input.acceleration.y;

        rigidbody.AddForce(dir * speed, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю в чем прикол, но оно даже не двигается=(
Код переписал прям точно. Скрипт к объекту прикреплен. Ригидбоди висит на объекте. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Всё хорошо. Ошибся в паре символов. Работает